# Expecation and Independence

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

Suppose that we have three independent random variables X,Y and Z where $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed and $Z$ has a symmetric distribution around zero. Intuitively, one would believe that
$$ \Pr(X\le Z |Y\le Z) = \Pr(X\le Z)  $$
due to independence. However, I don't know where to start to prove it. If we condition over $Z$, then we end up with an integral that not necessarily simplified further: $$ \int_z\Pr(X\le z ,Y\le z) dP(z) = \int_z\Pr(X\le z)\Pr(Y\le z) dP(z)  $$
Any hints? Is it at all true?

Comment: Maybe use Bayes ? $P(X \leq Z \mid Y \leq Z) \cdot P(Y \leq Z) = P(X \leq Z, Y \leq Z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general, consider the case where $Y$ is a constant. In that case, conditioning on the event that it is less than $Z$ gives you information about the value of $Z$.

Comment: my apologies... I just edited the question. especially for me identical distribution of Y and X is an important assumption which rules out many trivial cases (at least to me) where the statement does not hold.

Comment: Well even in that case you can consider them as constant and arrive at the same counterexample. I'd be interested in an example where the statement in your question is true.

Comment: Yes you are right! now that I think about it finding "examples" (as opposed to counterexamples!) is even more difficult! Thanks anyway